# Is it possible to scan for Wi-Fi using Python?

Tags: python, wifi

I am interested in writing a script in Python that is able to scan and show a list of nearby Wi-Fi networks. How could one do this? If possible.

Thanks.

Jake.

Comment: On which platform would your app be running? mobile devices or desktops? which OS?

Comment: Jake - you need to accept people's answers to your previous questions if you're going to have much hope of getting them to answer future ones.

Comment: @Will Dean - Yes true. I forgot. I will do it now. Thanks for reminding me.
@tomlog - For desktops running Windows 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. As far as the how is concerned, [this](http://www.devx.com/security/Article/34741/1954) might help you get started.

Additionally you can use the pywifi package to scan for all wireless devices in your area.

example:

```
 import pywifi
 import time

 wifi = pywifi.PyWiFi()
 iface = wifi.interfaces()[0]
 iface.scan()
 time.sleep(0.5)
 results = iface.scan_results()


 for i in results:
     bssid = i.bssid
     ssid  = i.ssid
     print(f"{bssid}: {ssid}")
```

Comment: Damn it. You posted just before I found bookmark with scapy: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/

Comment: FYI - This only worked once, now I get no results. The link to listed is also dead.

Comment: I guess it might have been me. Somehow I had two devices listed.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible using subprocess module

```
import subprocess
networks = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'network'])
networks = networks.decode('ascii')
networks = networks.replace('\r', '')
ssid = networks.split('\n')
ssid = ssid[4:]
ssids = []
x = 0

while x < len(ssid):
    if x % 5 == 0:
        ssids.append(ssid[x])
    x += 1
print(ssids)
```